# CodeIgniter Model

Tags: codeigniter, model, controller

My Model codes;

```
    <?php

Class index_model extends CI_Model
{
  public function index_model() {
        parent::CI_Model();
        $this->load->database();
    }
    public function uyelik(){
    $this->db->select("kadi");
    $this->db->from("uyelik");
    $query=  $this->db->get();
    print_r($query->result());
}
    
}



?>
```

My Controller Codes;

```
        public function uyeler(){
                $this->load->model("index_model");
                $this->index_model->uyelik;
            
        }
}
```

This code is wrong but i dont know where am i wrong, i started codes and 'it's print 404 not found'

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From CI documentation:

> Where Model_name is the name of your class. Class names must have the
>   first letter capitalized with the rest of the name lowercase. Make
>   sure your class extends the base Model class.

Source: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html

Answer (score 0):

As noted by ra_htial, the case for your model class is wrong:

> Index_model (not index_model)

Furthermore, in your controller, remember you're calling a function. Therefore it should be:

> $this->index_model->**uyelik()**;

Having said that, I don't know if you're just testing or what, but you shouldn't get into the habit of print_r() from your models. Models should only return the data to your controller that, in turns, would output what you want through a view.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$this->load->model("Index_model");
$this->index_model->uyelik();
```

instead of

```
$this->load->model("index_model");
$this->index_model->uyelik;
```

AND use

```
    <?php

Class Index_model extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::CI_Model();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function uyelik(){
    $this->db->select("kadi");
    $this->db->from("uyelik");
    $query=  $this->db->get();
    print_r($query->result());
}
```

> Where Model_name is the name of your class. Class names must have the
>   first letter capitalized with the rest of the name lowercase. Make
>   sure your class extends the base Model class.

check the documentation

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html

Answer (score 0):

if you need to call a method of a model you need to do this:

```
$this->load->model("model_name");
<br/>
$this->model_name->**methodUNeedToCall**();
```

rather than

```
$this->load->model("model_name");
<br/>
$this->model_name->**methodUNeedToCall**;
```